# Foundation framework error $key is not available in $foundation-pallette

Tags: wordpress, gulp, zurb-foundation, bower

I have foundation version 6.3.0 installed for a project and all of a sudden it started throwing the error "$key is not available in $foundation-pallette" I'm confused because I did not change anything in the bower component foundation color.scss file. I did update the settings file but nothing that I think would throw in error in the color.scss file.

So I did some research and could not find information particular to my situation. I tried reinstalling the bower components and also the sass node module.

Any help or point in the right direction would be great!

my terminal error image - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5s1m.png)

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I think there may have been something wrong with my local project file. I reverted to an old commit and that solved the issue. I think it actually wasn't the scss file, but I may have defined a color in my styles somewhere that actually wasn't defined in my settings.scss. Therefore, throwing the error.